# Como ficar 'ouvindo' para ver se SMS chegou no Android

Tags: android

Estou implementando um serviço de Two-Factor Authentication onde eu utilizo um gateway para envio de códigos de validação do cadastro do usuário. Quero implementar uma checagem automática no android para verificar se a mensagem chegou no dispositivo do usuário e não precisar que ele digite o código para depois ir validar o código, porque essa checagem na API tem um custo.

Comment: Mas aí perde boa parte da segurança. Além do mais não tem como verificar se o SMS realmente chegou ao usuário. Uma solução, para evitar o custo da API é você mesmo criar sua própria API para que o usuário digite o código recebido pelo SMS. Uma simples página com um formulário de um campo é o suficiente.

Comment: @DanielOmine o próprio whatsapp não faz isso? Verifica durante uns 5 minutos para ver se o código chegou no celular... Não entendi porque perde boa parte da segurança... O código é usado para verificar se o telefone do usuário existe..

Comment: no whatsapp ou qualquer outro app verifica o código se o usuário digitar.. Se receber o código e não digitar, não autentica.. Não existe isso de autenticar sem o código rsrs.. Como mencionei acima, não há como saber se o sms realmente chegou ao usuário. É quase como enviar um email. O envio pode ser bem sucedido mas não há garantia de que realmente caiu na caixa de mensagens do usuário.

Comment: Não sei se não formulei bem a pergunta, porque eu tenho certeza que ele  fica verificando durante 5 minutos aguardando o código chegar.. Outro app que também faz isso é o 99táxis

Comment: Esses 5 minutos é o tempo limite que usuário tem para digitar o código que recebeu no sms..

Comment: Mateus, existe um Broadcast que pode ser usado com um Receiver para tentar "interceptar" SMS's que chegam ao aparelho. Mas não é muito confiável, dado que alguns clientes de SMS do aparelho podem bloquear esse Broadcast (receber ele e não deixar repassar). Sugiro dar uma olhada nesse [tutorial](https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/an-android-app-to-intercept-incoming-messages/08/23/2015). Por experiência própria, é melhor registrar esse Receiver explicitamente (via `registerReceiver`) do que implicitamente no Manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo:

Adicione as seguintes permissões em  seu **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Ainda no manifest, adicione o seguinte `receiver` (dentro da tag `application`):

```
<receiver android:name=“seu.pacote.IncomingSMS">   
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

**IncomingSMS.java**

```
public class IncomingSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ phoneNumber + "; message: " + message);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```